# Mixing GDI+ with GDI

Tags: c++, gdi+, gdi

I'm using a third party library for drawing graphs. The library requires a HDC (GDI). But my application is using GDI+.

Q1: Is it safe to do this?

```
void f(Gdiplus::Graphics& graphics)
{
    HDC dc = graphics.GetHDC();

    // Call 3rd party lib functions using dc
    // ...

    graphics.ReleaseHDC(dc);
}
```

Q2: Some of the lib's functions require a bounding RECT struct (WinAPI). How do I calculate the coordinates for that rectangle if I'm using millimeters as page unit?

```
graphics.SetPageUnit(UnitMillimeter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Q1: yes, but you may need to change the coordinate system if the third party library cannot handle your coordinates ==> Q2

Q2: [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2309750/1850797) has some pointers for this (it is for the opposite direction, though), you will need to set the [mapping mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145045(v=vs.85).aspx) to MM_HIMETRIC, convert your GDI+ coordinates to integers of 0.01 mm and use [LPtoDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145042(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the pixel values.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I apply this method, I get negative values after the call to LPtoDP and the graph is drawn outside the visible area. Also, I've read that the MM_HIMETRIC mapping mode reverses the y-axis. This would seem to make sense combined with the negative values, but what about the origin then?

Comment: Some empirical tests, without changing the mapping mode, suggest that the unit is roughly 0.1mm. I could try to find a more accurate scaling factor, but that is dirty...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the y axis, you should be able to use negative y; the link for the mapping mode in the answer also briefly describes two origins used by GDI (window and viewport) and the extents of each